# Avoiding rest of the lines in python

Tags: python, dictionary

hi i am using try and except however when I got the print out from except if there are still some more information it continues to read it
when I use break it gives the error of break outside loop.
How do I stop python to read the rest of lines?
Thanks

```
def translate_word(word):

    try:
        return dictionary[word]
    except KeyError:
        print 'The ' + str(language) + ' word for ' + str(word) + ' is not found'

if language == "Italian" :
    create_dictionary('Italian')
    print "The Italian word for " + str(word) + " is " + str(translate_word(word))
```

And it prints out like this:

```
The Italian word for rubbish is not found

The Italian word for rubbish is None
```

Where as I only want it as:

```
The Italian word for rubbish is not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, if you have two `print` statements in your code, and both of them are executed, you will get two lines of output.

The root of the problem is that your `translate_word()` function does two things:

1. It returns the translation if the word is in the dictionary
2. It prints an error message if the word is not in the dictionary

Outside your function, when you call it, you have no way of telling which happened. So if the word is not in the dictionary, two things happen:

1. The `translate_word()` function prints an error message
2. The `print` statement prints the return value of `translate_word()` which, because you didn't return anything in this case, is `None`.

The reason it still does the second `print` is because you didn't tell it not to!

This code is kind of messy. Sometimes your function returns a translation, and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it prints a message, and sometimes it doesn't. This makes it hard for the caller (you, in this case) to plan the rest of the program.

What you should do is rewrite your `translate_word()` function so it does one thing: returns the translated word. If it can't, it should return `None`.

```
def translate_word(word):
    return dictionary.get(word, None)
```

(The exception handling is not necessary; the dictionary's `get()` method does this for you. In fact, you don't need the function at all -- `dictionary.get(word, None)` is not much longer than `translate_word(word)` -- but we will assume that in a bigger program it will do some other stuff and needs to be its own function. Also, it's slightly more readable.)

We return `None` rather than the string "not found" so that we can, if necessary, easily distinguish the following two situations:

1. The word is not found in the dictionary
2. The word is found in the dictionary, and its translation is the English words "not found"

`None` is not a string, so it would never be a translation for anything. This makes it safe to use as a flag value indicating that the word could not be found.

When you call the function, you then test the return value to see if the word was found. If so, you can print the translated word. Otherwise you can print your error message.

```
translated_word = translate_word(word)
if translated_word is None:
    print "The Italian word for %s is not found" % word
else:
    print "The Italian word for %s is %s" % (word, translated_word)
```

This way, all the code that does similar stuff is in one place, and it is easy to understand and reason about. This is referred to as *separation of concerns* by professional programmers. It is considered a good practice to have each chunk of code do one thing and one thing only, because it's easier to understand, write, and maintain. In particular, separating the input/output and data manipulation portions of a program is almost always going to make it more straightforward.

Consider: you lost track of what your program was doing, and your program has fewer than ten lines. Imagine how hard it would be to understand a program like this if it had a million lines *and you didn't write it!*

There are ways you can simplify this code even further:

```
translated_word = translate_word(word)
print "The Italian word for %s is %s" % (word,
    translated_word if translated_word else "not found")
```

Now you're talking Python!

Comment: Thanks, this was usefull to me as well! (I hope to be able to answer like this one day).

Comment: Thanks for this. I get tired of having to be the one to explain separation of concerns WRT I/O all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You usually `break` out of the loop:

```
for line in open('filename', 'r'):
  if line is 'foo':
    break

  # Line isn't foo. Keep going
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should simply do:

```
result = dictionary.get(word, 'Not Found')
print "The Italian word for " + str(word) + " is " + result
```

From the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):
`get(key[, default])` *Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.*

**Update:** `get` can be used even on the code in the comment.

Example:

```
create_dictionary('Spanish').get(word, 'Not Found')
```

Comment: the problem when I do this one that I have an if function like this if create_dictionary('Spanish')[word] == create_dictionary('Italian')[word]:same = " - same in both Italian and Spanish." else: same = "" which also gives error

Comment: @SarpKaya: I've updated my answer. Note that the `KeyError` exception is easily avoidable with the use of `get`, maybe this would help you. Otherwise please explain what `create_dictionary` does and what's your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the function entirely with a simple `dict.get`:

```
if language == "Italian" :
    create_dictionary('Italian')
    print "The Italian word for " + str(word) + " is " + dictionary.get(word, "not found")
```

Comment: The op may not want to end the program though, they might just want to skip over the remainder of the loop

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: "Break outside of loop" lead me to believe he's not in a loop and just wants to prevent the rest of the script from running. The question is rather vague though.

Comment: File "C:\Python25\lib\doctest.py", line 1228, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest __main__[5]>", line 1, in <module>
        translator('Italian', 'rubbish')
      File "H:\IND104\final\Project 4 - Italian-Spanish Translator\translator_q.py", line 146, in translator
        print "The Italian word for " + str(word) + " is " + str(translate_word(word))
      File "H:\IND104\final\Project 4 - Italian-Spanish Translator\translator_q.py", line 131, in translate_word
        sys.exit()
    SystemExit

Comment: hi I do that i still get the same message it prints out
    The Italian word for rubbish is not found
    The Italian word for rubbish is None

Comment: @SarpKaya, if you still get a `SystemExit` error you have not properly used my code.

Comment: I don't get SystemExit error
<br> I get The Italian word for rubbish is not found<br> The Italian word for rubbish is None

Comment: @SarpKaya, there was an error in the formatting of your code hence the confusion. In this case you don't need the function at all and can simply replace it with `dictionary.get(word)`. Edited answer above (again).

Answer (score 0):

Using ::

```
numCheck = 1
def translate_word(word):  
 try:         
  return dictionary[word]     
 except KeyError:         
  print 'The ' + str(language) + ' word for ' + str(word) + ' is not found'  
  numCheck = 0

if language == "Italian" and numCheck != 0:     
 create_dictionary('Italian')     
 print "The Italian word for " + str(word) + " is " + str(translate_word(word))
```

should help. If there is not much more operations to do, you can use exit() to escape from the script.